# Android Layouts for image buttons

Tags: android, layout, imagebutton

I am really new to android and I am just working out on layouts. I am interested in creating an image button menu for my first page. Anyone knows which layout is the best ? Thanks :)

Comment: what you want actually, please post wireframe hear.........

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ImageButton provided by the Android framework: [Android Image Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I have already created the imagebuttons and set some images for these buttons on an absolute layout but the problem is that when I add code in order to respond to the onclick events they do nothing. I am sure that the code is right but I guess something is wrong on my xml file that's why I asked if there is anything wrong with the layout.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply but I fixed it I just had to resize the images :D thanks